# How to create function with a parameter that will pass in as URL parameters through onClick() function?

Tags: reactjs

I have problem creating a function that has a parameter, and that parameter values comes from the dropdownlist which will pass that value once user clicks on the button. That value will pass to the componentDidMount to fetch the URL base on the parameter. There are many source in the internet but i couldnt find one that is passing values from a button to a API call instead. Thus i need help in this as i am first time trying to do this and hope my question clarifies. thank you.

This is my App.js code

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(){
     super();
     this.state={
        currencies: [],
        };



        }


handleChange =(event) => {

   let initialData = [];
        const url = `http://data.fixer.io/api/latest?access_key=ea263e28e82bbd478f20f7e2ef2b309f&symbols=${event.target.value}&format=1`

console.log("the url is: " + url)
 fetch(url).
  then(data =>{ return data.json();})
  .then(findData => {
   initialData = findData.rates
   console.log(initialData)
   this.setState({

        currencies: initialData,

        });
});

}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">

    {this.state.currencies.map(o => <div> {o.rates}</div>)} //<---Newly //added line which cause an error saying this.state.currencies is not a function.


        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p>
            Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
          </p>
     <h1 className="App-title"> Welcome to DKK website </h1>

        <div class="dropdown">
          <select id="select1" name ="currency" value={this.state.selectValue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                <option value="EUR">-- Selecting: NILL --</option>
                <option value="CAD">-- Selecting: CAD --</option>
                <option value="SGD">-- Selecting: SGD --</option>
                <option value="AFN">-- Selecting: AFN --</option>
        </select>


        </div>


<button className="pressMe" > Set Button </button>
<br/>
<br/>


     <a
            className="App-link"
            href="https://reactjs.org"
            target="_blank"
            rel="noopener noreferrer"
          >
            Learn React
          </a>
        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just put

```
 <select 
        value={this.state.selectValue} 
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
      >
```

You can call the fetch from the handleChange callback, something like

```
   handleChange = (event) => {
      let url = `http://data.fixer.io/api/latestaccess_key=ea263e28e82bbd478f20f7e2ef2b309f&symbols=${event.target.value}&format=1`
fetch(url)
.then....
    }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hi dorriz i have edited my codes base on your ideas however,  my api is an array thus it creates an error from compiler "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {CAD}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." and the line of code which cause this error is the "this.setState{ currencies: initialData} " Do you know why do i change to an array to overcome this error?

Comment: You mean the fetch call returns an array ? You should iterate over the array for example , use the map function of the array  e.g. this.state.currencies.map(currency => <div>{currency}</div>).  If your array is an array of objects then  this.state.currencies.map(o => <div>{o.currency}</div>). So, you would do that within you code like so <div className="App"> { this.state.currencies.map(o => <div>{o.currency}</div>)}</div>.  Hope that helps

Comment: yes i tried that but there is an error that says " this.state.currencies is not a function".

Comment: As a future debugging tip , when you encounter this , console.log or set a breakpoint and check your returned currencies ( or whatever) is an array . From the error it would seem it is not.  Also you should initially set you currencies to an empty array , e.g. this.state{currencies: []) in your constructor. Initially when your component mounts the currencies array is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use onChange method in the select component.
For example..

<select onChange={this.handleSelect}>
  <option value='1'>Option 1</option>
</select>

function handleSelect (e) {
 // here you can access to the event properties
 this.setState({ selectedOption: e.target.value });
}

// EXAMPLE

import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class MySelect extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // Assuming the data is an array of object with one position -> array[0]
      initialData: [{data1: 1, data2: 2, data3: 3}],
      selectedOpt: ''
    };
  }

  handleOpt = event => {
    this.setState({ selectedOpt: event.target.value })
  }

  render () {
    const { initialData } = this.state;
    // One way is to use the keys
    const optKeys = Object.keys(initialData[0]);
    return (
      <div>
      <select onChange={this.handleOpt}>
        {
          optKeys.map((key, index) => {
            return (
              <option key={`opt-${index}`} value={initialData[0][key]}>
                {key}
              </option>
            );
          })
        }
      </select>
        <button onClick={() => console.log(this.state)}>CHECK STATE</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, does that mean that i do not need to use the button to pass the value to the function?

Comment: Exactly, you can use onChange to handle the value each time a different option is selected.

Comment: Hi sandro, i have edited my codes base on your ideas however,  my api is an array thus it creates an error from compiler "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {CAD}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." and the line of code which cause this error is the "this.setState{ currencies: initialData} " Do you know why do i change to an array to overcome this error?

Comment: Your array seems to be an array of Objects -> [{key:value}].

Comment: i have updated the codes with array.map.prototype line however, an error says that "this.state.currencies is not a function. "

Comment: I've added an example to my answer

Answer (score 0):

I see two ways.

1) Store your select input current value in state (controlled components). You need onChange for your select.

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function() {
         return {
             value: 'select'
         }
     },
     change: function(event){
         this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     },
     render: function(){
        return(
           <div>
               <select id="lang" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                  <option value="select">Select</option>
                  <option value="Java">Java</option>
                  <option value="C++">C++</option>
               </select>
               <p></p>
               <p>{this.state.value}</p>
           </div>
        );
     }
});

React.render(<MySelect />, document.body);
```

and then you can get this value in your fetchData method as this.state.value.

2) Get value from ref in your fetchData method:

```
this.item.value
```

P.S. You button onClick event handler should be attached like this:

```
onClick={this.fetchData}
```

Comment: I have updated my codes but not sure is it the same as what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add parameter to your function on button click your should use arrow function:

```
onClick={() => this.fetchData(this.item.value)}  // to set parametr from ref
onClick={() => this.fetchData(this.state.value)} // to set parametr from state
```

Comment: Hi, i have edit my codes according to your reference however the compiler says that  "parsing error: unexpected token, expected ";" in line "getInitialState: function(){

Comment: can you help me verify my codes is it what you are saying. Thank you for your time and effort.